# Python. SeleniumWebDriver. How to operate with {Webelement} as iterable unit?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

got a problem with my trying to use clear selenium.webdriver.
I want to operate with element {WebElement} which was taken from list of WebElements.
Is it possible at all?

```
...

for button in web_driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, path):
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.web_driver, 10)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button.get_attribute("xpath")))):
        pass
        ...
```

But for real, the "button" has nothing useful for this.
Is it way to take its "xpath" or somehow check "element_to_be_clickable" during iteration?
Thanks advance!

Comment: get_attribute method will get the value of an attribute of the element.  Right now you are trying to get "xpath" attribute which would be something like <button xpath="value">  It's very unlikely a webelement would contain an attribute of "xpath".  XPATH is a locator used to specify/find a certain element in the DOM.  You have already obtained a webelement reference here (you are iterating through an array of them)... what is it you are trying to do here?

Comment: @browsermator, Thanks for the answer. For example, I am trying to find (by Xpath\class) in DOM all the buttons and then do "assert" for each one, sort only visible one and then submit it. I can use 'Selene', it allows us iterate list of webelements, which was found by XPath and communicate (as click, assert visible or etc.) with it properly. But the main goal was use clear WebDriver.

Comment: you don't want to do anything while iterating that would cause the DOM to change.  (So I'd avoid clicking while in the loop.)  You can get visible state via:  element.is_displayed() which returns a bool.  There is also is_enabled() which might be more useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, realy these two methods more enought for my cases!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @browsermator

> You can get visible state via: **element.is_displayed()** which returns a
> bool. There is also **is_enabled()** which might be more useful.

Maybe, it will be as well helpful as for me.